# TrueCrypt: Encrypted partitions showing up

Tags: windows, windows-xp, truecrypt

I used TrueCrypt to encrypt a non-system partition. The encrypted partition (i.e. the real, unreadable partition) has the letter `F:` and the partition that TrueCrypt decrypts on the fly has the letter `G:`.

I don't want to see `F:` anymore in My Computer. It's useless to me. I want to see only `G:`. How can I do that?

(I'm on Windows XP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are running Windows, you can remove drives from your view in the control panel:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools

there you click on "Computer Management". There again, in the  left sidebar is a entry "Storage" with a sub-point "Disk Management".

You can select your F-Drive, right-click on it and chose: "Change drive letter and Path".
You should now see a [F:] in the white field in the middle. Select it and click on "Remove". That will remove the drive letter from the drive but otherwise not  affect it.

If you need to have the drive again, simply do the same and add a letter instead.

Comment: This is how the TrueCrypt FAQ says it should be done. If you want to verify, see http://www.truecrypt.org/faq. Search the page for "disk management."